# Can I create a logger with lifetime during tests?

Tags: logging, junit, cucumber, log4j2, slf4j

I have an application that provides to run unit tests from UI. I run test with JUnit API (not from maven). I also use cucumber. And when user runs test inside my app cucumber create new application context (for tests). Moreover in the matter of business logic implementation I should write logs from tests in separate file and send it to UI when tests finished. So every running of test my app should create new log file, send him after finish and remove. Furthermore I use SLF4J-Log4j2 binding for my app. When I try to write logs using SLF4J-Log4j2 binding for all app I cant remove log file in the end because they used by logger. Can I create different logger only for test phase or configure existing to release log files after test finished? 
P.S. I've tried to remove current appender before file removing but its doesnt works

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="DEBUG">

    <Properties>
        <Property name="filename">${sys:catalina.home}/odysseyLogs</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{1} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <File name="File-other" fileName="${filename}/other.txt"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n" />
            <NoMarkerFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
        </File>

        <File name="File-env14" fileName="${filename}/bin/target/env14.txt"
            append="false">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} | %-5level | %c{1.} - %msg%n" />

            <MarkerFilter marker="env_14" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </File>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Root level="debug">

            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File-other" level="debug" />
            <AppenderRef ref="File-env14" level="info" />

        </Root>

    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case I would suggest creating a rolling file appender configured with a file pattern containing the system property of the test being run. I would then set the name of the test at the beginning of it and manually trigger a rollover at the end.

Comment: sounds good, but how can I set that sys property in configuration file (honestly I dont have a clue how to do that). If you can show some example it will be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you please provide an example? For dummies)